# Sum up column values from four different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

New to SQL

**Conditions:**

1. Find total number of customers for each area
2. Find total number of restaurants for each area
3. Max price of pizza sold by restaurants; if there are no restaurants selling pizzas in the area, it would be 0.

**Tables in SQL Query**

1. Likes(cname, pizza)
2. Customers(cname, area)
3. Restaurants(rname, area)
4. Sells (rname, pizza, price)

Sample database schema for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5cf74

**Expected Results**

```
| area   | totalCustomer   | totalRest | MaxValue
----------------------------------------------
| East  |      3           | 10        | 30
| North |      2           | 20        | 10
| South |      2           | 20        | 20
| West  |      1           | 0         | 0
```

**Current Results**

```
| area   | totalCustomer   | totalRest | MaxValue
----------------------------------------------
| East  |      3           | 5         | 30
| North |      2           | 10        | 10
| South |      2           | 10        | 20
```

- West area is not inside the table.
- What i want is to have ALL areas that have customers. Whether or not they are selling pizzas.
- If that particular restaurant does not sell pizza, it will still be included in the count of total restaurant.
- If the area only has restaurants that does not sell any pizza, the max value of the pizza would be 0.

**My SQL Code:**

```
SELECT c.area, COUNT(DISTINCT c.cname), COUNT(DISTINCT r.area), MAX(s.price)
FROM Customers c
JOIN Restaurants r ON r.area = c.area
JOIN Sells s ON r.rname = s.rname
WHERE area = all(
-- i'm thinking to use all to include every area that has customer. Whether or not it has any restaurants. 
)
GROUP BY c.area
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `'West'` is not showing up is that your last join needs to be outer (joins are inner by default):

```
SELECT
    c.area
,   COUNT(DISTINCT c.cname)
,   COUNT(DISTINCT r.name)
,   MAX(COALESCE(s.price, 0))
FROM Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Restaurants r ON r.area = c.area
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sells s ON r.rname = s.rname AND s.name='pizza'
GROUP BY c.area
```

Comment: @Yingyingyy That's odd - with `left outer` the join should produce rows for restaurants that don't sell pizza. You can't restrict `Sells s` rows in a `WHERE` clause, though, only in the `ON` clause (see edit).

Comment: @Yingyingyy You need left join on restaurants as well [modified sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdfbe/10).